# Data structure / algorithms for getting best and worst-scoring object from set

Tags: algorithm

My algorithm runs a loop where a set of objects is maintained. In each iteration there are objects being added and removed from the set. Also, there are some "**measures**" (integer values, possibly several of them) for each object, which can change at any time. From those measures, a **score** can be calculated based on the measures and the iteration number.

Whenever the number of objects passes a certain threshold, I want to identify and remove the **lowest**-scoring objects until the number of objects is again below that threshold. That is: if there are `n` objects with threshold `t`, if `n>t` then remove the `n-t` lowest-scoring objects.
But also, periodically I want to get the **highest**-scoring

I'm really at a loss as to what data structure I should use here to do this efficiently. A priority queue doesn't really work as measures are changed all the time and anyway the "score" I want to use can be any arbitrarily complex function of those measures and the current iteration number. The obvious approach is probably a hash-table storing associations object -> measures, with amortized O(1) add/remove/update operations, but then finding the lowest or highest scoring objects would be O(n) in the number of elements. `n` can be easily in the millions after a short while so this isn't ideal. Is this the best I can do?

I realise this probably isn't very trivial but I'd like to know if anyone has any suggestions as to how this could be best implemented.

PS: The language is OCaml but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Maybe a b-tree, where the key of each node is the score?

Comment: But the score changes all the time, in fact every score changes every iteration, due to the dependence on the iteration number.

Answer (score 0):

For this level of generality the best would be to have something for quick access to the measures (storing them in object or via a pointer would be best, but a hash-table would also work) and having an additional data-structure for keeping an ordered view of your objects.

Every time you update the measures you would want to refresh the score and update the ordered data-structure. Something like a balanced BST would work well (RB-tree, AVL) and would guarantee LogN update complexity.

You can also keep a [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) instead of the BST. This has the advantage of using less pointers, which should lower the overhead of the solution. Complexity remains LogN per update.

You've mentioned that the score depends on iteration number. This is bad for performance because it requires all entries to be updated every iteration. However, if you can isolate the impact (say the score is g(all_metrics) - f(iteration_number)) so that all elements are impacted the same then the relative order should remain consistent and you can skip updating the score every iteration.

If it's not constant, but it's still isolated (something like f(iteration_number, important_time)) you can use the balanced BST and calculate when the iteration will swap each element with one of it's neighbours, then keep the swap times in a heap, and only update the elements that would swap.

If it's not isolated at all then you would need at each iteration to update all the elements, so you might as well keep track of the highest value and the lowest ones when you go through them to recompute the scores. This at least will have a complexity of O(NlogK) where K is the number of lowest values you want to remove (hopefully it's very small so it should behave almost like O(N)).

Comment: Thanks! Storing in-object doesn't work because there are many instances of the loop running in parallel, referring to the same (immutable) objects. So only invariants are stored in-object, each loop has to keep its local stuff in its own state. As for the rest, it doesn't work because the scores change all the time, in fact due to the dependence on the iteration number *all* the scores change in *all* iterations. I guess I will stick to the hashtable + linear scan to find the lowest elements.

Comment: @andrepd check the edit. If the iteration is combined in simple ways into the score you might still be able to get better performance.  If you are going for linear scan, do it at the same time as the updates, the cache coherence should give you a speed boost.